# why does relative path is not working for <img src="""> in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I know the solution for this problem
The solution is to use "get_template_directory_uri()"

But Can someone please tell me why this relative path itself "/img/entry.png" is not working even though I'm using parent theme(Not child theme)

Before(Not working)

```
<img src="img/entry.png" alt="">
```

After(Working)　→　Why??

```
 <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/img/entry.png" alt="">
```

I putted index.php and Img folder at the same level in Theme folder as below. 
So why "img/entry.png" is not working?

```
 (Theme folder)
      |
      |--index.php
      |--img
          |-entry.png
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_template_directory_uri()` adds the path of the directory in which `img/`is located. If you want not to add that function then you have to add the path manually.

For example if your WordPress instance uses a theme called my-theme then this `/wp-content/themes/my-theme/img/my-image.jpg` could be served to img's src.

Comment: index.php is located at same level with Img folder.  So why I "/img/entry.png" is not working???

Comment: @Kazu25 starting slash before img indicates that you want to locate the file from root folder of your website not the folder in which this page is located.

Comment: Sorry Just mistake,　I mean  starting from "img" or "./img"

Comment: @Kazu25 YW, then an image in `http://site.tld/product/prod_name/` with `./img/my-image.jpg` as the src attribute value would try to locate the image in `http://site.tld/product/prod_name/img/my-image.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

the root of wordpress project is consisted od some directories such as 'wp-content' and 'wp-admin' and doesn't contain any folder named 'img'.

the 'src' attribute of images in HTML tag targets the root of the project then reads the url. so you should set your img folder path correctly from the project root.